# $\{\cos n+\sin n\}$ have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the $\{\cos n+\sin n\}$ have a convergent subsequence?
I am totally clueless.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, but in fact it has subsequences converging to any desired target in $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT: It’s a bounded sequence: $-2\le\cos n+\sin n\le 2$ for all $n$. That should be enough, but if not, a further hint is spoiler-protected below.

> See the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano-Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Should it not be $\sqrt{2}$, instead of 2?

Comment: Thank you so by bolzano Weirstrass  Theorem I can extract a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @miosaki: That’s exactly right.

Comment: @Tapu If it is true for $\sqrt 2$, then it is true for $2$.

Comment: @Tapu: I could have said $-1000\le\cos n+\sin n\le 1000$ and still been correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes you are correct, it is Bengali, my mother tongue.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right. They are speaking in bengali.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?